# Why is startForeground Notification Slow to Appear on First Call?

Tags: android, notifications, mobile-development

Soon after my app starts up I call startService then startForeground. I provide startForeground with a notification, but when it is called for the first time in the app the notification takes a while to appear. However, when I call stopSelf, and some event calls startService then startForeground again, the notification appears right away (this would be any time after the first call in the app). I figure this is because of some "cold start" scenario, but I'm looking for a more technical explanation. Anyone seen this or know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This delay is intentional as described here
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#foreground-service-notification-delay

Comment: Thank you! I found this in the documentation you sent as well which solves the issue entirely https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services#notification-immediate